# right way to use the write syscall linux

Tags: linux, assembly, stdout, nasm, system-calls

I can't find the right way to use the write syscall in 64bit nasm assembly. It just prints random signs. I've already checked the syscall numbers on my system.

```
section .data
string     db       'Hello World'

section .text
global main
main:
         mov rax, 1            ; syscall number for write
         mov rbx, 1            ; use stdout
         mov rcx, qword string ; 64bit adress of my string
         mov rdx, 11           ; length of my string
         syscall

         mov rax, 60           ; syscall number for exit
         mov rbx, 0            ; return code
         syscall
```

Comment: You should probably tag this question as `assembly` or `nasm` or similar.

Comment: The registers you're using don't match [this table](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64).

Answer (score 1):

The calling convention for amd64 (aka x86-64) is different from the one for i386. For instance, the first function argument comes into RDI. The register assignment used in your test matches i386 Linux syscall style, not the x86-64 one. Eventually, you didn't send any value in its proper place, except the syscall number itself.

[This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) has some notes on the proper method (but it misses change of a register for the kernel call case). [This document](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) is the original specification. The link shown by @Michael in his comment to your question contains practically the same but without detailed grounding, while being more practical just for syscall exploiting. Please follow them for your future activity.